# Recommendation for a book on calculus

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics, calculus

I am a high school student and know little about calculus. This includes simple integrals as well as more complex topics such as differential equations, which I feel are a prerequisite to solve and understand problems in physics.

Can you please **recommend a book on calculus** which also contains lots of practical problems?

Comment: This question might be a better fit on [Math.SE] or [MathEducators.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You are right, but one thing you have to have in mind is that the perspective also counts - some books are more heavy on theoretical aspects and abstractions, while other books are better suited for applications. This is why I feel this community can also contribute in providing recommendations for a book on calculus.

Answer (score 2):

I taught myself calculus in eighth grade, and I mostly learned it from Khan Academy. I know this isn't a book, but it is a splendid resource. The people there do a good job of explaining calc intuitively, and they also go through lots of different types of problems. [Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new) is the link.

Answer (score 1):

The one book I could definitely recommend is `Calculus` by **prof. Gilbert Strang**. There are several other his books on the topic, but this one covers everything you need to know about the calculus: from limits, derivatives and integrals to *vector calculus* which is very important for physics in general.

Here is his personal web site: https://ocw.mit.edu/faculty/gilbert-strang/

You can find the book's 2nd edition on his personal web site free of charge! In the book you will find a lot of problems that can help you understand calculus.

I can say one thing about his books - it is absolutely amazing how he explains complex topics simply and intuitively!

Comment: The link to Strang's book seems dead. Here is a working link. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/pages/textbook/